# Joining tables based on two columns based on MAX for another column

Tags: sql, join, max

```
SELECT *
FROM HistoricCall h
INNER JOIN Responses r
ON h.projectid = r.projectId 
AND h.caseId = r.caseId
```

The `HistoricCall` table has a column for number of attempts for each time that we've called someone (`h.callNumber`).

I'm trying to write a query that would display:

```
SELECT 
    h.callDate,
    r.cellmap,
    COUNT(*)
```

but only the `h.callDate` that corresponds to the highest `callNumber` for each record.

`HistoricCall`:

| projectId | caseId | callNumber | callDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100018 | 0000000001 | 1 | 2014-09-11 16:32:11.000 |
| 100018 | 0000000001 | 2 | 2014-09-11 20:43:01.000 |
| 100018 | 0000000001 | 3 | 2014-09-12 21:09:55.000 |
| 100018 | 0000000001 | 4 | 2014-09-13 14:58:14.000 |
| 100018 | 0000000001 | 5 | 2014-09-14 16:42:27.000 |
| 100018 | 0000000001 | 6 | 2014-09-16 21:54:09.000 |
| 100018 | 0000000001 | 7 | 2014-09-16 22:30:24.000 |
| 100018 | 0000000002 | 1 | 2014-09-11 16:36:17.000 |
| 100018 | 0000000002 | 2 | 2014-09-13 18:05:44.000 |
| 100018 | 0000000002 | 3 | 2014-09-14 16:39:03.000 |

`Responses`:

| projectId | caseId | cellmap |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 637850 | 0000000001 | 9101 |
| 637850 | 0000000002 | 9052 |
| 637850 | 0000000003 | 5071 |
| 637850 | 0000000004 | 5173 |
| 637850 | 0000000005 |  |
| 637850 | 0000000006 | 8062 |
| 637850 | 0000000007 | 0012 |
| 637850 | 0000000008 | 5292 |
| 637850 | 0000000009 | 9230 |
| 637850 | 0000000010 | 5187 |

Desired result:

| projectId | callDate | cellmap | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 637850 | 2014-09-11 | 0012 | 3 |
| 637850 | 2014-09-11 | 0014 | 7 |
| 637850 | 2014-09-12 | 0012 | 4 |
| 637850 | 2014-09-12 | 0014 | 2 |

Comment: share sample data and expected output

Comment: please tag with database platform

Comment: It looks like your expected results are not related to your sample data

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/121387/3404097) etc

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the celldate to date from datetime and simple group by should work.

```
SELECT 
    Max(h.projectid) projectid, -- if you need project id of call you can also include it in the group by clause
    h.callDate,
    r.cellmap,
    COUNT(*)
FROM HistoricCall h
INNER JOIN Responses r ON h.projectid = r.projectId 
                       AND h.caseId = r.caseId
group by cast(h.callDate as date), r.cellmap
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a join using a subquery to get the max callNumber by projectId and caseId grouping. There's no need to do a count since the callNumber is incremented according to your example above.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f307d7ee8444389f50ec7eeb0b40e42a) for reference

```
SELECT h.projectId              AS "projectId",
       cast(h.callDate AS date) AS "callDate", --cast as date
       r.cellmap                AS "cellmap",
       m.maxCall                AS "Count"
FROM   HistoricCall h
       INNER JOIN Responses r
               ON h.projectid = r.projectId
                  AND h.caseId = r.caseId
       INNER JOIN (SELECT projectid,
                          caseId,
                          max(callNumber) maxCall --get max call number
                   FROM   HistoricCall
                   GROUP  BY projectid,
                             caseId) m
               ON h.projectId = m.projectId
                  AND h.caseId = m.caseId
                  AND h.callNumber = m.maxCall
WHERE  r.cellmap IS NOT NULL --remove if empty cellmap values can be included
GROUP  BY h.projectId,
          cast(h.callDate AS date),
          r.cellmap,
          m.maxCall
ORDER  BY h.projectId,
          cast(h.callDate AS date),
          r.cellmap ASC
```